# How to dynamically instantiate a class of a specific generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

In the following example, I expected the type of the created object to be `SpecificSomething<Error>` but it turns out to be the base type, `SpecificSomething<Error>`

```
class Something<A> {}
class SpecificSomething<A> extends Something<A> {}

function createSomething<W extends Something<Error>>(ctor: { new(): W }): W {
    return new ctor;
}
const a = createSomething(SpecificSomething);
```

Why is `a` of type `Something<Error>` and not `SpecificSomething<Error>`? And how can I fix it?

[Typescript Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgFwBYEsB2BzAPAIIB80A3gL4BQokMsADssJgGabAIoY4EnTIAHqmTYAJvSRoseIqUpUqrAK7ZgqTPGzRgAJ2RgRXab3wB1AcNES4UnrICiu3fF3FiACnWuAXOWjYyADuHgCUfhYU4dAWZFTQCdD6qMq62oFBOqiuANxU1DRaEKjQYNAAvDr6hsjG9rgejMxsHHUyuKF5VAD03THoAJ7QmDCE0PCs0KgDTLbc7fhOLm6l4gHwJU0s7Jx2C0uuxAD8J0fQQA)

Comment: I don't have time to write you an answer right now, but you generally get better inference when the generic refers to the argument and you map from the argument to the return rather than the other way around.  Something along these lines `function createSomething<C extends { new(): Something<Error> }>(ctor: C): InstanceType<C>`

Comment: uh, hmm... but `InstanceType<typeof SpecificSomething>` will be `SpecificSomething<unknown>` and not `SpecificSomething<Error>`.  Without native support for higher kinded types in TypeScript (as in [microsoft/TypeScript#1213](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213)) it's tricky to try to do this.

Comment: @LindaPaiste This does work, feel free to post it as an answer and I'll delete mine.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing any solution that ends up with `SpecificSomething<Error>` and not `Something<Error>` or `SpecificSomething<unknown>`.  I'm not having any luck.

Comment: @jcalz You are correct, I do need the correct type and I misread the output of [my test page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKD2BbApgFwBYEsB2BzAPAIIB80A3gL4BQokMsADssJgGabAIoY4EnTIAHqmTYAJvSRoseIqUpUqrAK7ZgqTPGzRgAJ2RgRXab3wBhAcNETy0bMgDuACgCUALjhSesgKK7d8LqkFMRO6oEeZu7QAJLYEKhgasgAKgCeTObyVNC50Pqoyrra9g46qIHQkLHxicnpmWbEANxU1DRaCVXQALw6+obIxt64TozMbBzDMrgurVQA9AvQAOroadCYMITQ8KzQqBnIntwz+H4BQVXidvCocEws7JxeZxeBxAD835-QQA) when I said it did work... You are correct that what I need is higher kinded types and the person doing the actual work on this did point to this issue

Comment: Would you be interested in *simulating* higher-kinded types in TypeScript, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/qNB2gN)?  It doesn't happen automatically... it essentially requires that you have a little registry that you add to every time you create a new subclass of `Something`.

Comment: @jcalz This is really cool... but would require every developer to copy paste that really cool code in each subclass. Since it's boiler plate anyway, we'll just create a specific create function for each subtype until higher kinded types are available